# Drag and Drop - Create a new Grid Row while dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using [Sortable Grid from here](http://james2doyle.github.io/zepto-dragswap/) to perform a drag and drop in my app. However, I want to dynamically create a Row while dropping. 
I mean say if there are two rows in Sortable Grid. If user drags an element and thinks of creating the third row before dropping it, then he/she should be able to do it by dropping below the second row. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `div` below the boxes, and use `ondragenter` to prepare the program for a new row. I don't know how the plugin works, but this should help. Make the `div` however high you want, and that will be the distance beneath the list that can be selected (I recommend the height of the grid boxes)